# How to use a computed variable to return number of sub items using Knockout and Knockout Mapping Plugin

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I have some data with parent items, along with sub items for each parent. I'm trying to render the count of sub items for each parent, and if a sub item gets removed, the count gets updated.

Js:

```
var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS({
  items: [
    {title: 'red', subItems: [ {subTitle: '1'}, {subTitle: '2'} ] },
    {title: 'blue', subItems: []},
    {title: 'green', subItems: []}
  ]
});

viewModel.countSubItems = function(itemIndex) {
  return viewModel.items()[itemIndex].subItems().length;
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Html:

```
<!-- ko foreach: items -->
  <div>
    <span data-bind="text: title"></span> has <span data-bind="text: viewModel.countSubItems($index)"></span> sub items
  </div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

I'm getting something to the effect of viewModel.items(itemIndex) is undefined. Do I need to combine a function with a computable somehow? Live example (editable) here: http://jsbin.com/bonez/1/edit

Comment: countSubItems would be a good candidate for a ko.computed from what I can tell, but I don't see how you are trying to invoke it.

Comment: So is the double function(function( part of your pasted code just a copy paste error?

Comment: @PWKad He's invoking it in the span at the end of the template.

Comment: @KyleHale - whoops that was a typo. corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to wrap your ko.computed into a function and pass that function the itemIndex

```
viewModel.countSubItems = function(itemIndex)
{
  return  ko.computed(function(){       
    return viewModel.items()[itemIndex()].subItems().length;
  });
};
```

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/ziqig/2/edit)

Comment: the JSBin link you provided is not rendering the # of sub items in the rendered Html view.

Comment: @IanDavis sorry about that, update JSBin, forgot () for the itemIndex. Check it out.

Comment: Altho both were solutions that worked, this one allowed me to simply add a function onto my viewModel, not use another view model. Both are great tho, but this is the one I ended up using. Thanks all!

Comment: ps. I'm not sure why you have to do () for itemIndex(), but, whatever haha.

Comment: Because $index is a func.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do that is to extend your items mapping with a computed. In this example each parent items will have a computed called "countSubItems".

JS :

```
var itemViewModel = function(data) {
    var self = this;
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);
    self.countSubItems = ko.computed(function() {
        return self.subItems().length;
    }, self);
};

var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS({
  items: [
    {title: 'red',subItems: [ {subTitle: '1'},{subTitle: '2'} ] },
    {title: 'blue',subItems: []},
    {title: 'green',subItems: []}
  ]
}, {'items':{create: function (options) {return new itemViewModel(options.data);}}});

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

HTML :

```
<!-- ko foreach: items -->
  <div>
  <span data-bind="text: title"></span> has <span data-bind="text: countSubItems"></span> sub items
  </div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

With your example :
http://jsbin.com/visuvizi/1/edit

Comment: isn't it easier to just wrap the computed into a function that accepts itemIndex?

Comment: problem is that a new computed is created each time the function is used in an html binding or called from the javascript.

Comment: True but it is more elegant and simple for this particular case, and  it will not be to taxing on performance, it is a computed observing per item instead of one computed observing for all items in the array. I have implemented this type of code for large arrays and did not notice any performance issues even in IE8.

Comment: @RomainB - if I add to the viewModel an item with subItems, the newly added item does not have access to the countSubItems, it appears. Example: http://jsbin.com/visuvizi/4/edit

Comment: @IanDavis yes you need to add a new itemViewModel or even better use the mappedCreate function of knockout.mapping : http://jsbin.com/visuvizi/5/edit